# C# VS 2010 Find All References not finding everything

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference

Using VS 2010 C#.
I went to use `Find All References` and noticed it was only searching and listing files that were open in VS. I'm positive what i am looking for is used in may places. 
I know its working incorrectly, cause I'll open another .aspx file that uses it and it will then show up in the list.

I read some older posts on deleting the .ncb file, but the only on my computer is in a completely separate project and solution and folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your bin and obj folders and then recompiling and see if it works after that point.

Comment: Did not work for me, saw others suggesting this. Some say it maybe the way the projects are loaded.